# Question on Artin Proof of The Classification of The Groups of Order $12$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

In the book Algebra Ed2 by Michael Artin, in chapter 7.8 where Artin classifies the groups of order $12$, he considers a Sylow $3$-subgroup $K$ and a Sylow $2$-subgroup $H$ of order $4$.

Then $K\approx C_3$ and $H\approx C_4$ or $H\approx C_2\times C_2$. Therefore $H\cap K=1$, and then $HK=G$ as the product map is bijective. He proved that at least one of $H$ and $K$ is a normal subgroup, and consider them case by case.

In Case 3, when $K$ is normal, but $H$ is not, he writes:

> Then $H$ operates by conjugation on $K = \left\{1,y,y^2\right\}$. Since $H$ is not normal, it contains an element $x$ that doesn't commute with $y$, and then $xyx^{-1} = y^2$.

Why must it be true that an element of $x$ in $H$ does not commute with $y$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$HK=G$ and $H$ is abelian. If all elements of $H$ commute with those of $K$, then $G$ is abelian. This contradicts that $H$ is not normal.

Comment: Well yes, and i believe we could say if G is abelian then every subgroup is normal, contrary to this being the case where H is not normal?

Comment: Ah, yes indeed.